# Current Sensor Callibration

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, instrumentation, offset

I want to measure a low current (from 0 to 75mA) using the attached [schemtaic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Current/SparkFun_ACS712LowCurrentSensorBoard_v14a.pdf) for ACS712. The ACS712 sensitivity is 185mv and I want to use the max gain of 47 to input vout to a microcontroller(0-5vmax).

I want to make sure that this is how to correctly callibrate:

V=I x sensitivity x max gain
so when I is 0   V is 0
   when I is 75m V is 0.652125

Also I don't have any negative current so how do I connect the offset(R4)?

Comment: the image is unreadable, even the larger version when clicked

Comment: I hope this is clearer @Neil_UK

Comment: Why not use the circuit in the [application note](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/029/ACS712-pdf.php) Application 3?

Comment: I need to output the voltage on a microcontroller (5v max) so using the suggested difference amplifier (Vout=10.75-3.3v1)would give 10.75v when I=0. and 8.6v when I=75mA.@skvery

Comment: Not quite that's for a large current input of 30A. The App Note does not support 75mA full scale. You want to create 66,670mV/A

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method for R4 is to use V/2 using a resistor network with tolerance of <0.05% for matched equal values. The absolute value accuracy is unimportant.

[image]

### This would not work for you due to Hall sensor noise equiv of 100mApp with +/-30A range.

Instead use an R shunt.  1 Ohm
RT0805BRD071RL Digikey

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEm1sq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rail-Rail type needed with Gnd input sensing.

Comment: O.K lets say I use V/2 how do I callibrate this circuit ? @Tony Stewart

Comment: This is used to convert a bidirectional single supply referenced signal from V/2 now changed  to 0V for use with mono-polarity signals.   So you need Rail to rail Op Amp with high R values and with null input expect   0 output, prefer. 0.001 to show its not saturated. Ensure you have the correct polarity.  If small values are very important, I suggest offset to 0.1V for null input and then null out in software.

Comment: O.K but I still don't know when the current is 75mA for example what will be the output voltage. I want to get the relationship between the input current and the output voltage to the microcontroller.

Comment: If you want 0-75mA to become 0-5V with 185 mV/A setting then Gain = 5V/(185mV*75mA) =360 But this may not be the best choice for accuracy. Simply use a 75mV shunt R using 1 Ohm. This would be more accurate as typical noise is 7mV @66mV/A or 7/66m=106mA of noise. You can sense ground side or Vcc side with suitable diff amp. with gain of 5V/75mV= 106.7

Comment: O.K thanks a lot. So would you recommend a specific diff amp for the application ?

Comment: No but you can use design criteria to find one. CM range includes ground and Rail to rail output with low input offset voltage for 5V single supply.

Comment: There are several versions of the ACS712. The 5A one is 175mV/A, which would still be a pretty small signal for 75 mA, but might be do-able.

Comment: It is a question noise of signal to noise ratio that cannot be determined from question as given. But Hall sensors are very non-linear at low levels.

Comment: Here's the difference amplifier topology I know there's R4 so how do I apply the same equation here with no R4 ?

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't post an image in the comment but anyway I wanted to ask you something else shouldn't the gain be 5/75mV=66.67 ? and also what does the rightmost ground mean ?@TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: oh oh let me fix that mixup

Comment: O.K thanks a lot @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: I just want to make sure that I can use this circuit for any value of Rload as long as Imax to be sensed is 75mA to start hardware implementation @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: If  low EMI design in mind, it should be ok.  balanced , shielded if necessary, decoupled, othogonal orientation , twisted pair as required.  75mV shunt is pretty standard.